# How to make <h4> element on the same line with buttons?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this HTML:

```
<h4><span class="label label-default">1546 - some text</span></h4>
<div class="pull-left">  
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="list.saveItems();" ng-disabled="!list.currentItems.length || list.currentItemsStatus.id == 1">Submit</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="list.getItems()">Reload</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="true">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

How can I make `<h4>` element on the same row with the buttons on the right side?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to add the following CSS for the heading `<h4>`:

```css
h4 {
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h4><span class="label label-default">1546 - some text</span></h4>
<div class="pull-left">  
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="list.saveItems();" ng-disabled="!list.currentItems.length || list.currentItemsStatus.id == 1">Submit</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="list.getItems()">Reload</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="true">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

The default value of the `display` property is `block` so the heading (`<h4>`) takes the full width of the parent container. With `display: inline-block` the heading takes only the space needed.

---

**Bootstrap 3.3**

You can set the class [`.pull-left`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#helper-classes-floats) to the `<h4>` element. So you don't need additional CSS rules:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h4 class="pull-left"><span class="label label-default">1546 - some text</span></h4>
<div class="pull-left">  
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="list.saveItems();" ng-disabled="!list.currentItems.length || list.currentItemsStatus.id == 1">Submit</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="list.getItems()">Reload</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="true">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

---

**Bootstrap 4.0+**

Since Bootstrap 4.0 you have to [use `.float-left` instead of `.pull-left`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/migration/#utilities):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<h4 class="float-left"><span class="label label-default">1546 - some text</span></h4>
<div class="float-left">  
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="list.saveItems();" ng-disabled="!list.currentItems.length || list.currentItemsStatus.id == 1">Submit</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="list.getItems()">Reload</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="true">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Also replace `class="pull-left"` with `inline-block`, because `.pull-left` is for `float: left`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add some CSS for `h4` and `pull-left`-class:

```
h4{
  display: inline-block;
}
.pull-left{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

example:

https://jsfiddle.net/y6f0ddLg/