# Align button with text title bootstrap 4 beta

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Can someone explain me how to align `button` with text title using bootstrap 4 beta, I'm sure that this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42805129/how-to-make-h4-tag-on-the-same-line-with-buttons) does not work, because `pull-left` is changed.

I'm using [`float-left`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/float/) when I tried to align them, but the button is not exactly where it should be, so title should be on the left and button on right in the same line, here is my [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/copser/a6frvp9d/), so can someone explain me who to achieve this with new bootstrap 4 beta.

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-6">
      <h5><strong>BLOG TITLE GOES HERE</strong></h5>
      <div class="float-right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Read more</button>
      </div>
      <p class="blockquote-footer text-primary">By Branko Milosevic</p>
      <p>22.08.2017</p>
      Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I've provided **jsfiddle** example :P

Comment: Here sorry about that, and **jsfiddle** is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="foo">
            <h5><strong>BLOG TITLE GOES HERE</strong></h5>
            <div class="float-right">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Secondary</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p class="blockquote-footer text-primary">By Petar Pilipovic</p>
        <p>22.08.2017</p>
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
    </div>
</div>

<style>
.foo { display: flex; justify-content: space-between; }
</style>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a6frvp9d/1/

Comment: instead `.foo` you can use the built-in classes : `d-flex justify-content-between`. https://jsfiddle.net/a6frvp9d/4/  See: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/

Comment: @G-Cyr I never used Twitter Bootstrap, not familiar with it's build-in classes)